# Checking selected answers against correct answer in quiz in pHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this quiz app am working on using the codeigniter framework, but a having problem checking the selected answer against the correct answer. The questions are populated from a database, the database is such as below:

```
id | questions | opt1 | opt2 | opt3 | opt4 | correctAns
```

Please giving this structure how best can I get to check again the correct answer so as to score the candidate at the end of the quiz and also show them the questions they got correct and wrong.
I have a displayQuestions() in my Questions controller:

```
public function displayQuestions()
{
    $this->load->model('questions_model');

    $classLevel = $this->input->post('class_level');
    $subject    = $this->input->post('subject');

    $result = $this->questions_model->selectQuestions($classLevel, $subject);

    if ($result == false) {
        redirect('users/home');
    }

    $data['questions'] = $result;

    // $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('users/questions', $data);
    // $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar');
    // $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
```

A selectQuestions() in my Questions_model:

```
public function selectQuestions($classLevel, $subject)
{
    $query = $this->db
                    ->where('class_level', $classLevel)
                    ->where('subj_code', $subject)
                    ->get('questions');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this is how am displaying it in my view:

```
<div id="questions">
<?php
    // declare counter
    $i = 1;

    // array to hold correct answer
    $correctAns = [];

?>
<form method="POST" action="result/check">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <h2>Answer the following questions</h2>
        </legend>
        <ol class="question">
            <?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
                <?php if ($i <= 5): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $question->ques; ?>  </li>
                    <ol type="A">
                        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $question->ansOpt1 ?>"><?php echo $question->ansOpt1 ?></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $question->ansOpt2 ?>"><?php echo $question->ansOpt2 ?></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $question->ansOpt3 ?>"><?php echo $question->ansOpt3 ?></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $question->ansOpt4 ?>"><?php echo $question->ansOpt4 ?></li>
                    </ol>
                <?php endif ?>

                <!-- increase $i -->
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>
        <input type="hidden" name="correct_ans">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no functionality in the provided code that actually checks for a correct answer. You'll need to use a callback in form validation rules.

[CodeIgniter Form Validation Callbacks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)

In your controller:

```
private function verify_answer($q, $a) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ? AND correctAns = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($q, $a);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
}
```

You'll need to then create an array of correct and/or incorrect answers, depending on how you want to handle the output, based on whether a true or a false value is returned. Maybe you store them as an associative array with the question numbers as keys and loop through that and quiz end.

This may, by no means, be the most efficient way. Just "a way".

Answer (score 0):

Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is the communications protocol between web browsers and websites with data in cleartext.
Select one:
True Correct
False